# Cannot pull the uploaded image URL in swift UI

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, swiftui, firebase-storage

I'm trying to build an app. Now, I have the image picker and all the necessary stuff to get the image. However, when I create a user(cat in this case) in Firebase, I want to get the uploaded image url as well and add it to the imageUrl field in my collection.

I can successfully upload the image to Firebase Storage but cannot get the imageUrl to the collection for some reason.

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseStorage

class NewCatViewViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var name = ""
    @Published var age = Date()
    @Published var breed = ""
    @Published var gender = ""
    @Published var showAlert = false
    @Published var imageUrl: String? = nil
    @Published var catImage: UIImage? = nil

    // Declare imageRef as a property
    private var imageRef: StorageReference?

    var canSave: Bool {
        guard !name.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces).isEmpty else {
            return false
        }

        guard age < Date() else {
            return false
        }

        return true
    }

    init() {
        // Initialization code here if needed
    }

    func uploadImage(catId: String, uId: String, completion: @escaping (String?) -> Void) {
        guard let catImage = catImage,
              let imageData = catImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5) else {
            completion(nil) // Pass nil to indicate an error
            return
        }

        let storage = Storage.storage()
        let storageRef = storage.reference()

        // Create a reference to the file you want to upload
        let imageRef = storageRef.child("catImages/\(catId).jpg") // Use the same ID as the Firestore document

        // Upload the file to Firebase Storage
        let _ = imageRef.putData(imageData, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
            if let error = error {
                // Handle the error
                print("Error uploading image: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                completion(nil) // Pass nil to indicate an error
                return
            }

            // Image uploaded successfully
            print("Image uploaded to Firebase Storage")

            // Fetch the download URL
            imageRef.downloadURL { [weak self] url, error in
                if let downloadURL = url {
                    // After obtaining the download URL, call the completion handler with the URL
                    let imageUrl = downloadURL.absoluteString
                    self?.imageUrl = imageUrl // Set the imageUrl property
                    completion(imageUrl)
                } else {
                    // Handle the error with a detailed message
                    if let error = error {
                        print("Error getting download URL: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    } else {
                        print("Error getting download URL: Unknown error")
                    }
                    completion(nil) // Pass nil to indicate an error
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Add a method to access the image URL directly
    func getImageURL() -> String? {
        return imageUrl
    }

    func save() {
        guard canSave else {
            return
        }

        guard let uId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {
            return
        }
        let newId = UUID().uuidString

        let db = Firestore.firestore()

        // Create a newCat object without imageUrl initially
        var newCat = Cats(id: newId,
                          name: name,
                          age: age.timeIntervalSince1970,
                          gender: gender,
                          createdDate: Date().timeIntervalSince1970,
                          breed: breed,
                          imageUrl: "") // Initially, set imageUrl to an empty string

        db.collection("Users")
            .document(uId)
            .collection("Cats")
            .document(newId)
            .setData(newCat.asDictionary()) { error in
                if let error = error {
                    print("Error writing data to Firestore: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                } else {
                    print("Data written to Firestore successfully.")

                    // After the Firestore record is created, call the uploadImage function with a closure
                    self.uploadImage(catId: newId, uId: uId) { [weak self] imageUrl in
                        if let imageUrl = imageUrl {
                            // The imageUrl is available, you can use it here
                            print("Download URL of the uploaded image: \(imageUrl)")

                            // Update the imageUrl property of newCat and ViewModel
                            newCat.imageUrl = imageUrl
                            self?.imageUrl = imageUrl

                            // Now, update the Firestore document with the imageUrl
                            db.collection("Users")
                                .document(uId)
                                .collection("Cats")
                                .document(newId)
                                .updateData(["imageUrl": imageUrl]) { error in
                                    if let error = error {
                                        // Handle the error
                                        print("Error updating Firestore with image URL: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                                    } else {
                                        // Image URL successfully stored in Firestore
                                        print("Image URL stored in Firestore")
                                    }
                                }
                        } else {
                            // Handle the error
                            print("Error uploading image or obtaining download URL.")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Could you please help me? All the permissions allowed in Firebase. Thank you in advance!

I tried an update function but it didn't work as well.